# Save the curve obtained in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

Is there any way to save the curve obtained?

```
z = np.polyfit(x,y,100)
f = np.poly1d(z)
```

I want to save `f` so that one can use it without calling `polyfit` and `poly1d` repeatedly over the same training data. Just load `f` and use it.

Saving `f` will facilitate predicting values for dependent variable without retraining or possessing the training data. It'll save time when training data is considerably large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
np.save('example_filename.npy', f)
```

should work as well here as it would for any other numpy array. To get it back, just use

```
f = np.poly1d(np.load('example_filename.npy'))
```

The format used does not preserve the `poly1d` class, so reconverting the array returned by `np.load` is necessary, as shown.